# Вопрос по php

Tags: api, php, virustotal

Разбираюсь с api virustotal.
Вот что получилось уже получить, это вывод `<pre>$result</pre>` :

[image]

Вопрос такой, как мне вывести значения $result -> $scans -> * -> $result на экран циклом, не зная, какие именно имена под звездочкой?

И что надо прочитать, чтобы усвоить эту тему? Это что ООП? Объекты, класы? Что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Это что ООП? Объекты, класы? Что?

stdClass - базовый класс в системе с нулевым функционалом, используется, когда нужно создать "пустой" объект, не принадлежащий к классу, выполняющему какие-то конкретные функции.

> И что надо прочитать, чтобы усвоить эту тему?

Классы, но я бы рекомендовал вам читать все про ООП.

> Вопрос такой, как мне вывести значения $result -> $scans -> * -> $result

```
$vars = get_object_vars($result->scans);
foreach ($vars as $name => $var) {
    // делаем чо хотим, $name - ключ/название свойства, $var - само свойство
    var_dump($var);
}
```